# Get a specific numbers inside a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I get specific integers inside a string?:

```
mystring = "[RUN #1 3%,   2 secs]  2 threads:        6673 ops,    3511 (avg:    3333) ops/sec, 3.60MB/sec (avg: 3.42MB/sec),  0.56 (avg:  0.59) msec latency"
```

I want to get in this line the 3511, and 0.56

Comment: Note: there are multiple spaces between each word

Comment: What have you tried yourself? please show us the code...

Comment: I tried: re.findall(r'\bops,\b\s+\d{1,5}\s\b(avg:\b', line) for the first one,

Answer (score 4):

or you can not use regex in this case, which is maintainable and readable:

```
line = "[RUN #1 3%,   2 secs]  2 threads:        6673 ops,    3511 (avg:    3333) ops/sec, 3.60MB/sec (avg: 3.42MB/sec),  0.56 (avg:  0.59) msec latency"
answer = line.split()
print answer[9], answer[16]
```

Comment: Note that your input string is different that the one from the OP (it have multiple spaces), so your solution doesn't work as this. But it can work if you use `answer = line.split()`

Comment: fixed it thx. I copied the string but lost the extra spaces somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

From [regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), you can try this:

```
import re
s = '[RUN #1 3%, 2 secs] 2 threads: 6673 ops, 3511 (avg: 3333) ops/sec, 3.60MB/sec (avg: 3.42MB/sec), 0.56 (avg: 0.59) msec latency'
number_of_operations = int(re.search(r'ops,\s*([0-9]+)', s).group(1))
latency = float(re.search(r"sec\), ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+) \(avg", s).group(1))
```

Comment: I need the number 3511 (after "6673 ops,   "), and that returns 6673

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this. If you have multiple spaces and/or are generally unsure about the exact structure of your string it might be easier to not directly extract the numbers you want (like in [Guillaume Jacquenot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742102/1622937)) but do it in 2 steps:

First **strip all floats from the string**:

```
import re
mystring = "[RUN #1 3%,   2 secs]  2 threads:        6673 ops,    3511 (avg:    3333) ops/sec, 3.60MB/sec (avg: 3.42MB/sec),  0.56 (avg:  0.59) msec latency"
all_numbers = map(float, re.findall(r'[+-]?[0-9.]+', mystring))
```

Then **select the one you are looking for**:

```
print('ops/sec: {0}, msec: {1}'.format(all_numbers[5], all_numbers[9]))
```

Comment: No need to use regex because of the multiple spaces, `split()` will do the work

Comment: If you just `split()` you still end up with elements that are not convertible to float ('secs', 'threads:', ...). regex it to filter for numbers.